# Managing records of bugs and notes

Tags: xml, wiki, documentation, tags, query

I want to create a knowledgebase for a piece of software. I'd also like to be able to track bugs and common points of failure in that application. Linking knowledgebase articles to bug records would be a real boon, as would the ability to do complex queries for particular articles and bugs on the basis of tags or metadata.

I've never done anything like this before, and like to install as little as possible. I've been looking at creating a wiki with Wiki On A Stick, and it seems to offer a lot. But I can't make complex queries. I can create pages that list all 'articles' with a particular single tag, but I can't specify multiple tags or filters.

Is there any software that can help? I don't want to spend money until I've tried something out thoroughly, and I'd ideally like something that demands little-to-no installation.

Are there any tools that can help me?

If something could easily export its data, or stored data in XML, that would be a real plus too. Otherwise, are there any simple apps that allow me to set up forms for bugs, store data as XML then query and process that XML on demand?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

[MediaWiki](http://www.mediawiki.org/) has an XML export function, and I've seen it used for listing of known bugs before with some projects. It's very extensible, so if some feature is missing it shouldn't be too hard to find/code an extension (and the mailing list is pretty high quality). You could do metadata/tagging through the inbuilt category system, done by using `[[Category:foobar]]` on a page. I've used MediaWiki for a number of years, and I must say I have found it to be the most intuitive of all the wiki software that I've used.

Comment: Sounds interesting. Can I make complex queries? The limitation of Wiki on a stick is that I can't demand pages with two particular tags, only with or without one tag. Can I also perform searches for 'articles' edited or given certain statuses at particular time/dates?

Comment: The latter is certainly possible natively through manipulating `[[Special:RecentChanges]]`. The former is possible through an extension, but I've been out of the loop for a while, and can't remember off the top of my head what it is called.